# What is Spanish equivalent of webpage clinicaltrials.gov?

Tags: clinical-study, medical-records, database

Can you recommend any Spanish database of medical studies/clinical records, equivalent to English [clinicaltrials.gov](https://clinicaltrials.gov) ? Medical texts should be in Spanish, not webpage necessarily.

Comment: Do you just need the medical texts in Spanish? Or do you need the page to also be specific to a country other than the US? I do not have a resource for you, I just want to clarify for anyone who does have an answer.

Comment: _Do you just need the medical texts in Spanish?_ yes!

Comment: Alright! I just wanted to confirm for someone who hopefully has an answer for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EU Clinical Trials Register](https://www.clinicaltrialsregister.eu/ctr-search/search) provides clinical trials from EU and EEA, including Spain. Some trials are in 2 languages (country of origin plus English).